# How can I redirect my action to the root of the web site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following code in my controller to redirect my user after he has logged out:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new {
                        area = "Administration",
                        controller = "Menus", 
                        action = "Home" 
                    }
                )
            );
        }
```

I would like to redirect the user to / or the base URL (root) of my site. Is there a way 
that I can do this without having to give details of the area, controller and action?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

if you don't want to use `RedirectToAction` (for me is the right choice)
you can use

```
return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
```

**UPDATE**

As stated in the comments, this should also works

```
return Redirect("~/");
```

Comment: Url.Content should not be required. You can just do: return Redirect("~");

Comment: Perfect solution! Works great when using MVC Areas too unlike trying to use `RedirectToAction("Default");`

Comment: @CurtisYallop I had to do `return Redirect("~/");`